# How to check JAVA variable ${account} in jsp?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown-menu,  and I want to check if `${uaccount}` equals `admin`
show `users_info` item

I don't  konw how to write this in jsp . Please guide me

```
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                <%if(${uaccount}).equals('admin')){ %>
                    <li><a href="users_info">user info</a></li>              
                <%} %>
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">logout</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure that you have the JSTL library in your classpath, then import it into your JSP page with:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Now you can compare the string in JSP with:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
<c:if test="${uaccount == 'admin'}">
   <li><a href="users_info">user info</a></li>              
</c:if>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! By the way,What is  this type ````${xxx}````  called ? I want to know how can I  google this

Comment: It is JSTL expression

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
........
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
<c:if test="${uaccount eq 'admin'}">
  <li><a href="users_info">user info</a></li>    
</c:if>
  <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout">logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Explain why this is a valid solution.  It works and it's correct JSTL, but it's sorely lacking an explanation which is what's needed here.

Comment: JSP Expression Language (EL) is not allowed inside scriptlets. Hope it explains.